# How to remove a particular route in flutter using Getx?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-getx

I want to get a particular named route from the navigation stack and remove it using Getx.

Example: if I have this route stack:

A -> B -> C -> D -> E

and my current route is: Get.currentRoute = E

Then, how to delete/remove C from the route stack?
I need something like Get.deleteRoute(C).

Comment: Get.removeRoute(route) ??

Comment: What is your purpose of delete C? Did you navigate back from E to B?

Comment: I don't want to navigate back. I want to delete C.

Comment: The purpose is that if user navigate to C again, then I need to delete the old C from the stack.

Comment: most likely you need `pushReplacement` when pushing `D`

Comment: I can't, I'm now in E